# Will a JavaDoc and a little handwritten documentation be enough for a library?

Tags: java, javadocs

I am wondering if I wrote a little simple documentation and provided the JavaDoc, would it be enough documentation for a application GUI manager library for java?

Comment: Like many other things in computing, it just depends.  One of [the most useful libraries I know of](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) has a mere single page of documentation, whereas the [Oracle Java API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) could fill several tomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As GUI libraries / frameworks can follow a lot of different philosophies, I'd recommend some introductory texts, example code and visual results.

JavaDoc alone is only sufficient if the class model is self-explanatory, and I don't know any GUI framework where this is true.